# MySQL interview q: make a query that adds the number of worked hours in a given time period and display the name and total no. of hours worked

Tags: mysql, date, sum

You have a three colomn table with EmployeeName, Date, NumberOfHours. In this table you have the number of hours an employee worked for each day. Make a query that returns the number of hours worked by each employee during 2013-04-01 and 2013-04-30.

Answer (score 2):

```
select EmployeeName,sum(NumberOfHours)
from My_Table
where Date between '2013-04-01' and '2013-04-30 23:59:59'
group by EmployeeName
```

Comment: if you need that by day , just put the date un the select and the group by